# What is the simplest way for my C program to receive some file paths from configuration?

Tags: c, linux, posix

I have an application that is currently configurable via command line arguments

```
myprog  -fooFile 'foo.txt' -barFile 'bar.txt'
```

Command line parameters are a bit cumbersome so I want to allow for other avenues for these configurations but I am a bit disappointed that its looking more complicated then it taught it should be.

#### Solution 1: Use environment variables

I could make my program look for `MYPROG_FOO_FILE` and `MYPROG_BAR_FILE` envorinment variables. The implementation is just a `getenv` but env variables are global and add clutter and are also hard to configure. Specially for GUI apps because many window managers don't source ".profile" during initialization.

#### Solution 2: Use a configuration file

Since the fooFile and progFile are kind of static configuration values, it seems like its better to put those in a configuration file somewhere:

```
fooFile = /home/hugomg/foo.txt
barFile = /home/hugomg/bar.txt
```

But afaik there is no easy way in C to read an arbitrarily long string from a file. Do I really need to make a loop that keeps reallocing a buffer just for this?

Alternatively, since all my values are file names, is there some `#define` somewhere specifying the maximum size of a path string?

Comment: You are a ~34k user and you didn't think of this question as opinion based? And yes, there is include `limits.h` and use `PATH_MAX` or `MAX_PATH` on windows.

Comment: I outlined 3 different possibilities but I don't know which one is gonna end up being the simplest on to implement. So I think the question has a definite answer.

Comment: Implementation simplicity is not a good criterion, think of portability and scalability. Also, you can search the web for a `key` `value` file reading library, I am sure there would be options.

Comment: @iharob: my restriction that all configuration files are file names means that scalability is not an issue (its not worth adding dependencies for some XML parser lib because I don't need most of the features there). In the end the most simple solution is likely to be the most portable one as well.

Comment: You might like to have a look at `libconfig` (http://www.hyperrealm.com/libconfig/).

Comment: Linux has [getline](http://linux.die.net/man/3/getline), which handles lines of arbitrary length.

Comment: @MOehm: You should put that as an answer

Comment: @hugomg: Okay, I've re-written my comment as a short answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your configuration file approach with a simple syntax looks good to me.

Since you are on Linux, you could use [getline](http://linux.die.net/man/3/getline) to read the file. It can handle lines of arbitrary length and manages the memory allocation for you.

Answer (score 0):

If your application has a GUI, you may want your user to configure it from within the application. In this case, you may want to use a database to store your configuration; that way you can validate your data on it's way in, so your user can't write a bad config file. I would suggest using SQLite for this: it provides a full database in a file, and is pretty easy to use.

http://www.sqlite.org/

Comment: I'm looking for something simpler than that :) Preferably without adding more dependencies to the project.